# Lost my old ubuntu account?

Tags: networking, email

I logged in on my Ubuntu account, and changed my email address to my GMAIL address and SAVED it.  I de-registered the old email address that I used to log on to my ubuntu account.  But when I tried to log on with the new email address (GMAIL) that I saved, it could not find it anymore.  I tried to log in with the password I used with the deleted email address, and still wouldn't take it.

I tried clicking on 'Forgot Password', and it showed me a link to the "Create account".

The email account I use to log into Ubuntu is of my previous work, which is why I decided to change it to my personal email address instead.   But I should still be able to log on using my NEW email (i.e. GMAIL address), right?

Comment: What did you lose your password on? The AskUbuntu website, your Ubuntu system, or is it something else? This question is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Jeff Doesn't seem to be the Ubuntu system. Looks like Ubuntu SSO/Launchpad login to me.

Comment: @Stewie Tee, could you be more specific, please?

Comment: @wyphan I do not know anything about Launchpad, so I wouldn't know.

Comment: sorry for the confusion guys.   Jeff - wyphan is correct.  I was trying to log onto review.opendev.org (Gerrit) and it uses the Ubuntu SSO.   So when I wasn't able to log on with my new GMAIL address,  I tried logging back on Gerri with my original work address and I was able to get in.   I went to Settings and I didn't see my GMAIL address there, so I tried adding my Yahoo email address instead and set it as my preferred email and saved it.  (1/2)

Comment: I still wasn't able to log onto opendev Gerrit (review.opendev.org)  using the new Yahoo email address, so I tried the original work address to log in and I was able to get into Opendev Gerrit again.  Now here is the WEIRD thing:  (a) my Opendev Gerrit account shows my Yahoo email address as the primary account  (b) all my opendev Gerrit commits are now associated with my GMAIL account (and no longer my work email, which is what I wanted),  but (c) the GMAIL address is not listed in my email addresses in Ubuntu One (it lists my orig work email and my Yahoo email addresses).   (2/2)

Comment: So  is there a way to associate my opendev Gerrit commits to my Yahoo email address?  Sorry for the long-winded question.    Thank you for your patience, guys.

Comment: I don't know, but I would expect it'll require confirmation from the old email account first (to ensure it's not another person trying to *steal* the account).  I'd chase up using @wyphan's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried contacting Ubuntu SSO support?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ISD

There is an email address near the bottom of the page. I'm sure they will be glad to assist you in recovering your Ubuntu account.

Comment: Should that not work, they can also try [filing a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-identity-provider/+filebug).

Comment: Thank you @wyphan - I sent email to isd-support@canonical.com.  But just as an aside,  in my investigation I found that my opendev account has switched correctly to my personal email address, but my opendev Gerrit commits has not switched.    Hopefully Ubuntu ISD-Support can handle that.